# How to ignore param added to XSLT file if no param given?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xslt

In my XSLT file I have to add a param that let's the user pick a "genre" of book, this is selected from a dropdown list and a button is clicked to update the XSLT param to the selected genre

[image]

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ListOfItems/*[Genre = $Genre]"/>
```

My XML file looks like:

```
<ListOfItems>
 <Product>
    <Title>Book A</Title>
    <Price>15</Price>
    <Author>J Smith</Author>
    <Genre>Medical</Genre>
  </Product>
  ... etc
</ListOfItems>
```

The user selects the genre from a drop down and presses a button

```
Protected Sub loadGenre_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loadGenre.Click
    Dim xslArg As XsltArgumentList = New XsltArgumentList()
    xslArg.AddParam("Genre", "", "" + genreSelect.Text)
    Me.xmlProducts.TransformArgumentList = xslArg
End Sub
```

My issue is that I would like ALL products to display initially, is there a way to toggle the XSLT param on and off depending if the user has picked a genre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
You should be able to use an xsl:if statement like:
```
<xsl:if test="$Genre = ''">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ListOfItems/*"/>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="$Genre != ''">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ListOfItems/*[Genre = $Genre]"/>
</xsl:if>
```
you could also use `<xsl:choose>`
````

Comment: Awesome! this sort of worked, I made an edit request with the code that worked. I couldnt find an ELSE tag so I used two ifs and checked the condition again.

Comment: @Ari If you need ELSE, use [`xsl:choose`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose).

Comment: Note also that you could reduce this to a one-liner: `<xsl:apply-templates select="ListOfItems/*[Genre = $Genre or $Genre='']"/>` - if you like that sort of thing.